# Plugin to allow registered users to customize their layout

Tags: customization

We are in the process of creating a resource website for developers and I would like there to be an element of personalization available to the end user.  So if you are a python developer you can specify that the python articles show up at the top so you don't have ot sift through a bunch of other articles that aren't relevant to you.  Or if you prefer podcasts/audio over video content you can have the most recent podcasts on your front page and nix the video feeds.

Anyone have suggestions on the best way to achieve this?  Is wordpress a good/bad option for this or should we be looking at something like joomla or drupal ?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of different concepts and resources to achieve this, I would do something like this..

It may be easier to implement this in a theme. You could include template files in your plugin, or the plugin create shortcodes to output data.

Add usermeta profile preferences.
You would want to add a select field that gets populated from a taxonomy (Tags maybe).
And maybe a radio group with 'All', 'Videos', 'Podcasts' etc, auto pulled from another taxonomy (Category or maybe Post Type)

I would say it best/easiest to make two sections. One with 'preferred feed' and other as 'all'. 
Use PHP in your shortcode-logic/template to get the current user meta and test to see if they specified all/specific terms. If they have, run a WP_Query with those values, otherwise dont show the section at all. And then show the 'all' section after. 
You could integrate the two WP_Queries using some logic based on getting the current usermeta, but I wouldn't want to limit your users to finding more interesting content. Especially if it's a 'learning' site for devs. You could also just put the 'else' part of the usermeta test to show the 'all' feed.

Pretty high level answer but hopefully that will point you in the right direction!

Here's a quick tut on adding user meta, the other stuff is readily available in the codex
http://www.e-dirts.com/4528/how-to-add-custom-user-meta-data-field-on-wordpress-user-profile/

Comment: Thanks Joshua, exactly what I needed to hear in order to get my butt off in the right direction